# Hello I want to detect using a Bluetooth iBeacon, but it does not work well. How can I solve it?

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, beacon

Hello I want to detect using a Bluetooth iBeacon, but it does not work well. How can I solve it?
I am testing by connecting with a real mobile phone, not an emulator.

> 2020-06-13 22:42:01.729 26437-26728/com.example.beacon
>   D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON 2020-06-13 22:42:01.729
>   26437-26728/com.example.beacon D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find
>   callback wrapper 2020-06-13 22:42:08.353
>   26437-26728/com.example.beacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON 2020-06-13
>   22:42:08.353 26437-26728/com.example.beacon D/BluetoothLeScanner:
>   could not find callback wrapper

Is that it continues to be filmed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements BeaconConsumer {
    protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;


    PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(List<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
        // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have declared FINE_LOCATION permission in your AndroidManifest.xml and you [go through the steps to obtain that permission from the user](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html).

Once you have completed those steps, if you still see these messages, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42821272/1461050

Comment: Thanks to that, I solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please tell us what specifically solved your problem?  This information may help other people.  And if this answer provided that information, it is proper to make the answer as accepted.

Comment: FINE_LOCATION set it up, but didn't request permission directly.
I checked whether permission was granted or not, and when I didn't know that I needed to write the code to request, I went to the option of the mobile phone and clicked'Permit permission' on the permission side of the downloaded app, so I knew the importance of permission request. Thank you. And thank you for your kindness.

And I'm sorry for not being able to speak English.