# BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

While developing the app I got this problem.
Some Android devices cannot find the Bluetooth connection (Not all of them)
And it shows this error.

```
D/BluetoothLeScanner(27109): Start Scan with callback
I/BluetoothAdapter(27109): STATE_ON
I/BluetoothAdapter(27109): STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(27109): could not find callback wrapper
```

I have tried to add Fine Location permission, but there is no luck.

```
<uses-permission android:name="Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Since you are withholding your source code, we are forced to guess. A first search here on Stack Overflow yields this result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42821272/8124605