# Xamarin Forms BLE - doesn't work with Android 7.0, works with Android 4.4

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project, where I use Plug-In Xabre for Bluetooth LE. To test it I use Android 7.0 device.
The problem occurs when I start scanning for devices nearby.

Following is my code for scanning devices:
deviceList.Clear();

```
        status = "SCANNING";

        adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
        {
            deviceList.Add(a.Device);
        };
        if (!ble.Adapter.IsScanning)
        {
            await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
        }
```

Last night I could get the scanned device. But since then it can't scan anymore.
On the Output Line in visual studio:

- D/BluetoothLeScanner( 8436): could not find callback wrapper

But, when I tried it with a Android 4.4 Device, it works like what I am expecting, it can scan devices nearby.

Anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41149864/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover the first answer told me to ignore it, but if I ignore it I can't scan anything. And I have the Location Service turned on

Comment: Is the location services turned on at your App level? i.e. Are you requesting runtime access from the user? https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: @SushiHangover in which file should I wrie the code manifest.permission... ?

Comment: You should take a look at : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: @SushiHangover I will take a look on it. But I did create another app to test only the bluetooth function, and without implementing the method from that xamarin blog, it works.